# How to solve $\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x\mathrm{ln}x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

here is the integral:

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x\mathrm{ln}x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$$

What is the best way to  solve it? I was thinking of by parts but I did not find exact result then, if there is substitution in the denum, it does not "cover" $\mathrm{ln}x$ and I don't get more-less table integral (or similar).

Are there easier ways?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: that is irrelevant without a reason. As said many times, anyone is able to use WA.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Unfortunately, Sonnhard will continue to post comments that give an answer, right or wrong, but don't reveal how one would arrive at the proposed answer.  To wit, [check his comment under the question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2292018/help-me-compute-the-sum-of-the-series/2292036#2292036)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HINT:**

Enforce the substitution $x\to 1/x$ and watch the "magic" ensue.

---

If you would like to proceed less efficiently, integrate by parts with $u=\log(x)$ and $v=\frac{-1/2}{1+x^2}$.  Then, use partial fraction expansion to write $\frac{1}{x(x^2+1)}=\frac1x-\frac x{x^2+1}$.  Be mindful that the integral is improper and that evaluation of the terms involved in the integration by parts scheme do ***not *** individually converge.  Rather, their sum converges.

Comment: What do you mean by "enforce the substitution?"

Comment: @grace Which word did you not understand?  "Enforce" means to "apply," "implement," "administer," "execute," etc.

Comment: It wasn't so much the word, it was the technique for solving the integral. It's been a while since I've taken calculus and I don't remember using anything like that, the only substitution I really recall is u-substitution.

Comment: @grace If this works better for you, let's say "Let $x=1/u$ instead of "Enforce the substitution $x\to 1/x$.  Does that work?

Answer (score 7):

$$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{x\log x}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx \stackrel{x\mapsto \frac{1}{z}}{=} -\int_{0}^{1}\frac{z \log z}{(1+z^2)^2}\,dz$$
hence the value of the integral is simply $\color{red}{\large 0}$.
The absolute convergence of the original integral follows from
$$ \forall x>0,\qquad \left|x\log x\right|\leq \max(1,x\sqrt{x}).$$

---

As an addendum, it might be interesting to know what is the area that gets "canceled out", i.e. what is the value of the integral
$$ I_1=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{z}{(1+z^2)^2}(-\log z)\,dz \stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=}\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{z}{1+z^2}\,dz=\color{red}{\frac{\log 2}{4}}. $$
Integration by parts (IBP) here is performed by taking $\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{1+z^2}\right)=\frac{z}{2(1+z^2)}$ as a primitive of $\frac{z}{(1+z^2)^2}$, in order to ensure the existence of $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{1+z^2}\right)(-\log z)$.

Comment: You followed my hint nicely. ;-))

Comment: @MarkViola: LOL. (+1) as a token of gratitude for your hint :)

Comment: Thanks Jack!  I'm sure you wouldn't have had a clue otherwise ... LOL

Comment: Hi, The magic trick shows that the integral is zero, meaning that the area under the x-axis is equal to the area above the x-axis, but....shouldn't you also show that the areas themselves are finite? Just showing that the areas "cancel" is not sufficient for an integral to be convergent, is it?

Comment: @imranfat The integrals converge absolutely.

Comment: @MarkViola Yes that is true though, I just thought that was a kind of necessary part of the answer.

Comment: @imranfat: if the integral converges absolutely, then the integral above the $x$-axis is necessarily some finite number. We do not have to explicitly calculate this number.

Comment: @Clayton True. I just remember an old post where I provided a similar answer as Jack and Mark did, and I was made aware of the remark I made. If the substitution $x=1/t$ gives a zero but the areas themselves are not finite, then.....But here it is clear

Comment: @imranfat: anyway you are right, to prove that the integral is absolutely convergent is important, so I clarified that point.

Comment: @FelixMarin: many thanks, now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

By parts, it becomes

$$\Bigl[-\frac {\ln (x)}{2(1+x^2)}\Bigr]_X^{+\infty}+\int_X^{+\infty}\frac {dx}{2x (1+x^2)}$$

with $t=x^2$,
we find at the end

$$\frac {\ln (X)}{2 (1+X^2)}-\frac {1}{2}\ln (\frac {X}{1+X^2})$$

$$=-\frac {X^2\ln (X)}{1+X^2}+\frac {\ln (1+X^2)}{2} $$

Now compute the limit when $X\to 0^+$ to find zero.

Comment: Glad you followed my hint ... ;-))

Comment: What happened to the integral from $0$ to $1$?

Comment: @MarkViola Is it okay now.